# Instant App Icon (on Pixel) cause crash when the main App get installed using copy-&-install

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

On Pixel2 Phone, after we launched Instant App, we could see the Instant App Icon as the BuzzFeed icon shows on the top left of image
[image: Instant Apps Icon on app icon in "Search Apps" field]

This is cool, as it allow one to open the Instant App with default URL on the phone.

However if we install the main App using the Copy-Into-Device-&-Install (e.g. Fabric Beta), the Icon didn't get replace. When we click on the Icon, it will try to launch the main App, but crashes with

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.mypackage.app.MyApplication: java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10166 cannot explicitly add accounts of type: com.mypackage.app.account
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5743)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I think it's a google bug. But thought would be good to check out further if anyone know this is something we should handle on our main App instead.

(note: using GooglePlay to install the Main App doesn't cause the problem, as the Instant App Icon goes away and replace with the main App Icon)

Comment: I have reported this issue to Google as well in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72463086

Comment: Can you link me to the API?